# How to make git rebase to handle incremental part only

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I have two branches, develop branch and feature branch. Several co-workers and I work on feature branch to add new big features, it could be several months. And co-workers in other teams will fix bugs or even add tiny features in develop branch. I'm going to rebase from develop branch regularly, perhaps, once a week. I notice that even I rebased last week, why I have to start over from the beginning, what I've already rebased last week. Is there a way to handle the incremental part only? Perhaps, some parameters are missed.

Comment: It sounds to me like there is a misunderstanding on the nature of how rebase works. If you chose to rebase only the _new_ parts from the feature branch (which is possible, with specifying more options to rebase), you would be leaving _behind_ the _old_ parts of the feature branch. Am I missing somerthing? Perhaps an ascii-art branch example could help explain what you mean.